# Why is P{$\cup_{k=2,4,6,...even}[\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}]$}=$\sum_{k=2,4,6,..even}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$

Tags: probability, summation

Question: Given the uniform pdf on $[0,1]$,$f(x)=1$; x $\in [0,1] $.Define the cumulate distribution function (cdf) $F$ as the probability of the event {$x:x \le r$}as a function of $r \in \Re$:

$F(r)=P((-\infty,r])=\int^{r}_{-\infty}f(x)dx$

Find the probability of the event:$G$={$w:w \in [\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}]$ for some event $k$}=$\cup_{k=even}[\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}]$}

Solution:

This is part of some question's solution,and i don't know why is the left formula equal to the right formula,can anyone explain it to me?thankyou!

P{$\cup_{k=2,4,6,...even}[\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}]$}=$\sum_{k=2,4,6,..even}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$

Comment: More context is needed to answer this. The probability of the disjoint union is the sum of the probabilities. Since $2^{-(k+1)}$ is the width of the interval $[2^{-k},2^{-(k+1)}]$, this would be true if the probability space was $[0,1]$ with a uniform measure.

Comment: @MikeEarnest i have edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ we have $P([a,b])=b-a$ whenever $0\leq a\leq b \leq1$. Just apply this to $a=\frac 1 {2^{k}}$ and $b=\frac 1 {2^{k}}+\frac 1 {2^{k+1}}$. [The intervals are disjoint when $k$ is restricted to even integers].